# Making submit button active when there is text in textfields - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a script which check when two textfields are not empty it does automatic submission. it picks the variables from the localstorage and places them in the textfields.

```
if (localEmail != null && localPwd != null) {


     $('#form1').submit();

  }
```

and i also i have a script which disables the submit button when all textfields are not filled.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
var $input = $('#form1 input:text'),
    $register = $('#button_id');    
$register.attr('disabled', true);

$input.keyup(function() {
    var trigger = false;
    $input.each(function() {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            trigger = true;
        }
    });

    trigger ? $register.button('disable') : $register.button('enable');

});

});
```

now my problem is when the page loads for the second and subsequent times and there are variables from the localstorage in the textfields, the submit button still remains disabled and the automatic submission fails.  Now i want the button to remain active when there are variable in it so the automatic submission can be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In document ready do an additional check for input values and disable the button

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $input = $('#form1 input:text'),
        $register = $('#button_id');

    $input.each(function () {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            $register.attr('disabled', true);
            return false;
        }
    });
    $input.keyup(function () {
        var trigger = false;
        $input.each(function () {
            if (!$(this).val()) {
                trigger = true;
            }
        });

        trigger ? $register.attr('disabled', true) : $register.removeAttr('disabled');

    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $input = $('#form1 input:text'),
        $register = $('#button_id');

    $input.each(function () {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            $register.attr('disabled', true);
            return false;
        }
    });
    $input.keyup(function () {
        var trigger = false;
        $input.each(function () {
            if (!$(this).val()) {
                trigger = true;
            }
        });

        trigger ? $register.attr('disabled', true) : $register.removeAttr('disabled');

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <button id="button_id">button</button>
</form>
```

Comment: see this fiddle with input values present: 
http://jsfiddle.net/abhiklpm/tkxp26L7/1/

Comment: i changed 'trigger ? $register.attr('disabled', true) : $register.removeAttr('disabled');' to 'trigger ? $register.button('disable') : $register.button('enable');' and it worked

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
  $input.each(function() {
    if (!$(this).val()) {
        trigger = true;
    }
```

under document ready function.

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
  
 var $input = $('#form1 input:text');
 $register = $('#button_id');   
   $register.prop('disabled', true);
  //$register.attr('disabled', true);
  
   $('#button_id').on('click',function(){alert('hi');});
  
  function checkInputs(){  
   
         $input.each(function(e) { 
            if (!$(this).val().length < 1) {
                      trigger = true;
                           } else  
                                {trigger = false;}
              });
       trigger ? $register.prop('disabled',false) : $register.prop('disabled',true);
   }
checkInputs();
$('#form1 input:text').on('keyup',function(){checkInputs();});


  



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1">
<input/>
<input />
<button type="button" id="button_id" >Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: can you please phrase it into my script cos when i did nothing happened

Comment: it will work now, ignore the tiny bit of code at the top of my answer, forgot to take it out and if I go in to edit it I lose all the changes

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are not achieving the desired behavior is because you are only updating the button's `disabled` property when a `change` event is fired from the input element(s), which are not fired by default upon page load.

The solution is to therefore move the function involving updating the button's status into a separate one, which we will call upon runtime (e.g. DOM ready) and then again when the `change` event is fired on element(s) of interest:

```
var updateButton = function() {
    var trigger = false;
    $input.each(function() {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            trigger = true;
        }
    });

    trigger ? $register.button('disable') : $register.button('enable');
};

// Update button status on DOM ready
updateButton();

// Update button status on keyup
$input.keyup(updateButton);
```

On a side note, please use `.prop()` when dealing with binary attributes:

```
$register.prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: you mean i should write a seperate script with the answer you provided?